# Python SSL Cert error despite no browser expiry

Tags: python, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I am a python noob and was trying to scrape random websites (without abusing). [This site](https://resultsarchives.nic.in/cbseresults/cbseresults2018/class12zpq/class12th18.htm) caught my attention and my code ran:-

```
import requests

url = 'https://resultsarchives.nic.in/cbseresults/cbseresults2018/class12zpq/class12th18.asp'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    ":authority": "resultsarchives.nic.in",
    "Origin": "http://resultsarchives.nic.in",
    "Referer": "https://resultsarchives.nic.in/cbseresults/cbseresults2018/class12zpq/class12th18.htm",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
}
x = range(8397, 8398)
i=0
for i in x:
    payload = {
        'regno': '6529437',
        'sch': '12345',
        'cno': str(i),
        'B2': 'Submit'
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    open('scrape.html', 'a', encoding="utf-8").write(response.text)
```

When executed, an SSL Certificate Expiry Error is thrown. However, browsers (chrome/firefox) work fine, and note the certificate to expire in Dec. 2022. The error ran:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='resultsarchives.nic.in', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /cbseresults/cbseresults2018/class12zpq/class12th18.asp (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

If I process the same code using the Http version(s) of the site(s), it works fine!

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Python 3.9.7

Comment: I had an idea that you might have had an old version of Python and it was an intermediate cert stored somewhere within Python that had expired.  But 3.9.7 is quite recent so that's probably unlikely.

Comment: you can run `post(..., verify=False)` to skip this problem.

Comment: this page has new cert created `12 Nov 2021` so maybe Python gets some old cert from proxy servers, buffers, caches, etc. Maybe after few days it will get correct cert.

Comment: It is probably the case that the root certificates on **your** machine need updating to get the ISRG Root certificate **and** the Let's Encrypt R3 intermediate that was signed by ISRG.